# Turtle Graphics: How to shift label upwards?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am learning Python and am trying to edit the code which has the following error:

> Each height label is partly covered by the top segment of its bar. Can you modify the `drawBar` code, moving the label up slightly but not changing the bar? Hint: The label cannot be drawn during the polygon fill sequence.

I have tried to `def` a new function, but that didn't work. Can you locate the error/edit?

```
def drawBar(t, height):
    """ Get turtle t to draw one bar, of height. """
    t.begin_fill()               # start filling this shape
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.write(str(height))
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(40)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.left(90)
    t.end_fill()                 # stop filling this shape

xs = [48, 117, 200, 240, 160, 260, 220]  # here is the data
maxheight = max(xs)
numbars = len(xs)
border = 10

wn = turtle.Screen()             # Set up the window and its attributes
wn.setworldcoordinates(0-border, 0-border, 40*numbars+border, maxheight+border)
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")

tess = turtle.Turtle()           # create tess and set some attributes
tess.color("blue")
tess.fillcolor("red")
tess.pensize(3)

for a in xs:
    drawBar(tess, a)

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: did you try to use `t.write()` after `t.end_fill()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move up then set pen up, move forward, write text, move back, set pet down.

```
t.penup()
t.forward(2)
t.write(str(height))
t.forward(-2)
t.pendown()
```

---

Minimale working code

```
import turtle

def drawBar(t, height):
    """ Get turtle t to draw one bar, of height. """
    t.begin_fill()               # start filling this shape
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(height)
    
    t.penup()
    t.forward(2)
    t.write(str(height))
    t.forward(-2)
    t.pendown()

    t.right(90)
    t.forward(40)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.left(90)
    t.end_fill()              # stop filling this shape

xs = [48, 117, 200, 240, 160, 260, 220]  # here is the data
maxheight = max(xs)
numbars = len(xs)
border = 10

wn = turtle.Screen()             # Set up the window and its attributes
wn.setworldcoordinates(0-border, 0-border, 40*numbars+border, maxheight+border)
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")

tess = turtle.Turtle()           # create tess and set some attributes
tess.color("blue")
tess.fillcolor("red")
tess.pensize(3)

for a in xs:
    drawBar(tess, a)

wn.exitonclick()
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to move up and right

```
t.penup()

t.forward(2)
t.right(90)
t.forward(3)

t.write(str(height))

t.forward(-3)
t.right(-90)
t.forward(-2)

t.pendown()
```

[image]

Comment: This was simple to follow thanks! I did not know you can t.write(str(height)) while t.penup()

Comment: if it couldn't `write` when `penup` then you could use `pendown` directly before `write` and `penup` directly after `write`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by saving the state (its position and heading) of the turtle, moving it a little bit to right before drawing the label, and then restoring its state afterwards.

Here's what I mean:

```
def drawBar(t, height):
    """ Get turtle t to draw one bar, of height. """
    t.begin_fill()               # start filling this shape
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(height)

    posn = t.position()          # Save position.
    heading = t.heading()        # Save heading.
    t.right(90)                  # Point to the right.
    t.forward(1)                 # Move over a little.
    t.write(height)              # Display the label.
    t.goto(posn)                 # Restore position.
    t.setheading(heading)        # Restore heading.

    t.right(90)
    t.forward(40)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.left(90)
    t.end_fill()                 # stop filling this shape
```